# Show that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin\left(kx\right)}{k^2}$ is not an elementary function

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, elementary-functions

> Prove that:$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin\left(kx\right)}{k^2}$$is not able to be expressed using elementary functions.

When plugging this into WolframAlpha it returns:
$$\frac 12i(\mathrm{Li}_2(e^{-ix})-\mathrm{Li}_2(e^{ix}))$$
Where $\mathrm{Li}_n(z)$ is the [polylogarithm](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Polylogarithm.html).

I've never hear of the polylograithm before, but after reading about it, I have a vague idea how WolframAlpha got there, however I don't know how to show that $\mathrm{Li}_n(z)$ is non-elementary. My other idea would be to turn the sum into an integral using:
$$\int_0^xf(t)dt = \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^nf\left(i\frac xn\right)\frac xn$$

Comment: $\sin(kx)$ is the imaginary part of $e^{ikx}$, hence your series is the imaginary part of $\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{e^{ki x}}{k^2}=\text{Li}_2(e^{ix})$. It is interesting to point out that the *real* part of such dilogarithm is a piecewise-quadratic function.

Comment: On the other hand, a *proof* that $\text{Li}_2$ is non-elementary requires a *definition* of *elementary function*. What is yours?

Comment: I guess the one that math.stackexchange uses - that being "functions of one variable built from a finite number of exponentials, logarithms, constants, and nth roots through composition and combinations using the four elementary operations (+,–,×,÷)."

Comment: Well, in such a case, $\text{Li}_2$ is given by a primitive of $\frac{\log(x)}{1-x}$ and [Risch algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm) speaks.